# Could not spawn process for application with Rails 4, Passenger and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

```
[ 2014-09-04 07:22:07.0615 14334/7f66e7b44700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not  spawn process for application /home/myapp: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
```

Error ID: 96892690

```
[ 2014-09-04 07:22:07.0708 14334/7f66e5a2e700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 96892690. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```